# Node.js https fails, whereas browser, `curl` & `wget` succeed?

Tags: node.js, https, http-headers, http-status-code-403, node-https

Succeeding requests:

```
$ url='https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/tools/xml2rfc/trunk/cli/xml2rfc/data/xml2rfc.css'
$ curl "$url"
$ wget -qO - "$url"
$ python -c 'import webbrowser; webbrowser.open("'"$url"'", new=2)'
```

Failing request:

```
$ echo 'require("https").get("'"$url"'", res => console.info("statusCode:", res.statusCode, ";"));' | node
```

Output of failing request:

```
statusCode: 403 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to get a file from a remote server which you do not have access. You have to set user agent when you make a call to a remote server with nodejs https package. Try this code:

```
let https = require('https')
let pageUrl = 'https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/tools/xml2rfc/trunk/cli/xml2rfc/data/xml2rfc.css'
let url = require('url')

let options = url.parse(pageUrl)
options.headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'request'
};
let req = https.get(options, (res) => {
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    let data = ""
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk
    })

    res.on('end', (chunk) => {
        console.log("ended")
        console.log(data)
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Weird that `User-Agent` needs to be set, and that that isn't the default.